# What does && do/mean when assigning ? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, operators

I know that && can be used to check if the both conditions are satisfied when it is used in a conditional statement but how do you explain 
 **full[i][j] = open[i][j] && full[i - 1][j];** ?? 
 In case we are reading this piece of code how do we explain this? 
 
 Notice that **full and open** are two 2D *Boolean arrays*

```
//i = column j = row
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                full[i][j] = open[i][j] && full[i - 1][j];
               //^^ what happens here?
}
```

Comment: Did you run this code to see what really happens? I think it could help to improve the understanding of that expression.

Comment: Yes i did, step by step, i can understand what it is doing, what it is for, wasn't familiar with && used with =(assign) operator. So wanted to learn what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
 full[i][j] = open[i][j] && full[i - 1][j];
```

Means that that `[i][j] && full[i - 1][j]`    will resolves to a boolean and assigning it as a boolean element in another array.

Comment: Which means that as we are dealing with boolean values here assignment(=) is actually working as a conditional operator too right? it will get assigned to the full[i][j] if the both values open[i][j] and full[i - 1][j] are true(?).

Comment: I understand what it is doing, but can you explain what is happening here? is = act as a conditional operator too?

Comment: No, full[i][j] just gets set to the resulting value of the expression `open[i][j] && full[i - 1][j]` which is a boolean. = just sets full[i][j] equal to this value and is thus just an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think (Not 100% sure) that it is assigning values,
When we are using primitive data types we can use a single & to do bit wise anding, 
While we are doing the same for boolean values,

```
full[i][j] = open[i][j] && full[i - 1][j];
```

Means we are assigning `anded boolean value` of `open[i][j]` and `full[i-1][j]` to `full[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the values of full array are false.

Initially for i=1 and j=0. 
Value of full[0][0] will false. So whatever open[][] value is , full[1][0] will have false value.

Correct me if I understand your question worong.

Comment: Actually full is an already processed array, some indexes are true and some are false, what it actually do is checking if any vertical line of the matrix contains all true values.